# How to validate Azure Managed Identity setup of app service is working as per expectation0 in azure portal

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-managed-identity, azure-appservice

**Tech Stack:**

- .Net 6 web api
- Microsoft.Sql.Sqlclient 4.0.1 (Nuget package add Azure App service(API) - System
  generated Managed Identity).
- Azure.Identity
- Azure Sql database - setup to accept API APP service managed identity.

I am using EFcore in API to connect to Azure sql database and this setup is working as expected in my workstation from VS2022(using from vs2022 credentail). the API connects with database without any issues.
But when the same code is deployed to Azure APP service, API is not able to connect to Azure Sql instance.

- **Error**: ManagedIdentityCedential.GetToken failed to acquire token.

Issue: Azure App service "System-managed" identity works fine in local using VS2022 but is not working in App service

- **Request**: Do we have a way to check if the Managed Identity setup is
  working as per expectation in Azure Portal.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please share the source code?

Comment: Have you add the service dependencies when you publish the project in vs2022 ?

Comment: By the way, please follow the official doc to troubleshoot the issue.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-connect-msi-sql-database?tabs=windowsclient%2Cef%2Cdotnet

Comment: did you grant the managed ideneity permission to access your sql db ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Jason Pan and Thomas for the comments.

Make sure you have enabled the `Managed Identity` in the `Azure App service`.

[image]

As mentioned in the [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/identity?view=azure-cli-latest), check the identity status by using the below command.

```cs
az webapp identity show --name KeyVaultAPIMay24 --resource-group YourRG
```

[image]

- Also add the necessary roles.

[image]

As mentioned by Thomas check whether you have configured SQL Database with correct permissions to use Managed Identity by Amine Teffahi.

We can also configure the `Managed Identity` from the Visual Studio itself.

[image]

[image]

After publishing the App again, you need to Connect to the Identity Platform.

[image]